# putting a colorbar matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

How would I go about putting a colorbar by the side of my graph in matplotlib. My graph is a matrix that has 155 rows and columns and I want my colorbar to line up with matrix.
the data in the colorbar can be random. I just want a colorbar lined up next to my graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `pyplot.colorbar` function. See the documentation at http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=colorbar#matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar for the function's parameters and so on. Also if you want more control you might want to look at this example: http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/colorbar_only.html.